# When is $\operatorname{gr}_I (M)$ finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, graded-modules, graded-rings

> When is $\operatorname{gr}_I (R)$ (I mean associated graded ring of $I$) finite? When is $\operatorname{gr}_I (M)$ finite?   if
>   1) $R$ is non-Noetherian ring ,
>   2) $R$ is Noetherian ring and $M$ is not finite $R$-module  ,
>   3) $R$ is Noetherian ring and $M$ finite $R$-module,

Comment: What do you mean by finite? What are the conditions of the ring and module?

Comment: If you are asking if $gr_I(M)$ is a finitely generated as $gr_I(R)$-module, then is is if $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module. In fact $gr_I (M) = gr_I(R) [gr_I(M)]_0 $. Also, $gr_I(R)$ being Noetherian can be seen directly. It is generated by $[gr_I(R)]_1$ over $[gr_I(R)]_0 = R/I$. Since $R$ is Noetherian $R/I$ is Noetherian. Also $[gr_I(R)]_1 = I/I^2$ is a  finitely generated $R/I$-module. Now the statement follows from the Hilbert basis theorem.